# Elsevier Editorial System: is this scam?

Tags: peer-review, scams

Today I received two **suspicious** emails from *Elsevier Editorial System*:

- the first email is a **registration confirmation** to the platform

> Dear XX *Name Surname*,
>
> You have received this system-generated message because you have been
>   registered by an Editor for the Elsevier Editorial System (EES) – the
>   online submission and peer review tracking system for Information
>   Sciences.
>
> The EES account for Information Sciences has been added to your
>   existing Elsevier profile.
>
> Please note: The username for your Elsevier profile is the E-mail
>   Address to which this message was sent.
>
> When you log in to EES, you may update your password and other
>   personal information by selecting the "change details" option on the
>   menu bar at the top of the page. Any updates you make to your contact
>   and log-in information will be reflected in any other Elsevier product
>   account that is linked to your Elsevier profile.
>
> Please visit our FAQs for more Elsevier profile information.
>
> Kind regards,
>
> Elsevier Editorial System Information Sciences
>
> If you need further assistance, please visit our customer support site
>   at *some link* Here
>   you can search for solutions on a range of topics, find answers to
>   frequently asked questions and learn more about EES via interactive
>   tutorials. You will also find our 24/7 support contact details should
>   you need any further assistance from one of our customer support
>   representatives.

- the second email is a **review invite**

> *Re: Some Paper Title*
>
> *by Some List of Authors*
>
> *Submitted to Some Field*
>
> Dear XX *Surname*,
>
> As we believe that you are an expert in the field of the above
>   referenced submission, we would like to invite you to review it.  We
>   would very much appreciate it if you could find the time to examine
>   this article with regard to its suitability for publication in
>   Information Sciences. To view the submission for first inspection,
>   please click: *some link*
>
> You are allowed 21 days to upload your review report.
>
> If you accept the invitation as you are willing to review this
>   submission, please click on the link below:
>   *some link* Convince
>   yourself that any documents you upload are anonymous, so that the
>   author cannot retrieve your identity.
>
> If you decline the invitation as you are not willing to review this
>   submission, please click on the link below:
>   *some link* If it is not
>   possible for you to referee this article within this period, we would
>   appreciate it if you could inform us as soon as possible. We may be
>   able to extend the due date for the review. We would appreciate
>   suggestions for alternative reviewers in case you decline to review.
>
> In case none of the above links seem to function properly, please
>   click: *some link* (or copy and paste into your web
>   browser) and log-in as a reviewer.
>
> Make sure to select the "Reviewer" button.
>
> Your username is: *my email*
>
> If you need to retrieve password details, please go to:
>   *some link*
>
> Please save this information in a safe place.
>
> We recommend you to change your password to something more memorable
>   upon initial connection to Elsevier Editorial System.
>
> Please return your review comments within 21 days, which will start
>   from the date you on-line accept to review.
>
> As a reviewer you are entitled to complimentary access to Scopus and
>   ScienceDirect for 30 days. Full instructions and details will be
>   provided upon accepting this invitation to review.
>
> In addition to accessing our subscriber content, you can also use our
>   Open Access content.  Read more about Open Access here:
>   *some link*
>
> PLEASE NOTE: Information Sciences invites authors to submit any
>   supplementary computer code, data snippets, algorithms and other
>   machine readable structures in re-usable .txt format with their
>   article as Inline Supplementary Material. We ask editors and reviewers
>   to include Inline Supplementary Material in their review process to
>   verify that it is relevant to the paper, appears to function according
>   to any descriptions in the main text, and does not have any
>   superficial flaws or errors , and importantly that the title, caption
>   and description for this material are correct.
>
> Thank you in advance for your kind help and we hope to hear from you
>   soon.
>
> Kind regards,
>
> *Name Surname, Titles Titles*

---

I perceive the fact that an account was created for me without my consent, I didn't even know the service existed before receiving the email, as a **red flag** for a possible **scam**. I also find it weird that in the second email I am requested to *click some link/access to the service* both in case I accept or decline the unsolicited review invitation.

I don't know personally whoever signed the email, and from the list of his/her publications it looks like the chances we "met" at some of the conferences I have previously attended in are pretty low.

Since I am somewhat *"new"* to *Academia*, I would like to ask whether this kind of **aggressive review request** is common and normally socially acceptable, or whether this is some kind of *scam* I have never met before.

Is it **safe**, or maybe I should say **sane**, to give a look at the paper and maybe review it? So far I didn't click any of the links in the email, since I didn't setup an appropriate *sandbox environment* for doing this task alone yet.

---

**ETA:** There are a couple of questions on this website that seem related with mine, like [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/85935/invitation-to-review-for-an-unknown-journal?rq=1). However, there also appear to be several questions about the *Elsevier Editorial System* on this board, which somehow seem to corroborate the notion that the aforementioned system is not a *predatory/malicious service*, as it was indeed the case in the linked question.

Comment: "Somewhat new to academia" ... Presumably there are more senior professors where you are.  Ask them.  Back when I started, an editor would ask me in person to do a review, or by a letter (you know, paper document, delivered physically not electronically).  For all I know, this sort of electronic request is the usual nowadays.  Is it safe?  Well, don't give them any financial information...

Comment: I agree with Shake Baby that this is typical. What usually happens is that someone on the editorial board decides to invite you, looks up and puts in your e-mail address, and then all of this is automated. You could contact the academician whose name is on the e-mail, and ask if they initiated the request.

Comment: Also, is 21 days a normal review time in your field? In my subject (math), 3-6 months is much more common (and 1-2+ years is not unheard of), and saying "You are allowed 21 days" would be ridiculous. Nevertheless, it is common for publishers (or automated e-mails sent by publishers) to try to unilaterally impose such deadlines. I would double check with a colleague before considering myself bound by such a deadline.

Comment: @Anonymous I believe maths is the exception here. 21 days is perfectly normal in my field. A challenging review would take me one to two days, usual is half a day net time.

Comment: Extremely profitable multinational publishers making you, a professional, work for free while charging your institution a very substantial sum of money to get the end product of your work _is_ a scam :-) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cost_of_Knowledge

Comment: This is usually not a scam.  You may not have an account in a journal, and an editor identified you as a suitable reviewer.  So he/she will first create an account, and then use it to send you an invite.  You can choose to reject or ignore the request.  Nothing will happen.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the usual way reviewer invitation arrives. Go for it.

(Maybe check if the email and the links you received are really from an Elsevier domain).

Comment: Yes, these are the typical emails you get from the Elsevier review management system. Most likely not a scam.

Comment: Or at least no more of a scam than Elsevier usually is ;-)

Comment: If you had already been registered in the system, you would have received only the second email.  In any case, you are allowed to decline any review invite.  Even if you decline this invitation, you could go ahead with the registration: then you will be in the system the next time an Elsevier journal editor wants your opinion on a paper.

Answer (score -1):

It is normal, but not a good practice. You might want to ask them how much they pay. Not that they usually pay, but it makes them aware they should.